How to find loadsh dependency
I am running an older version of laravel (6) in combination with vue2. I recently received a vulnerability alert regarding loadsh.
I have tried to look for the package and could not find it either in
package-lock.json or running npm ls, yet when I remove the node_modules folder and re-install using npm install I see loadsh being installed.
How can I find which package is using loadsh?

This could be XY problem. Consider explaining further. It is npm ls lodash, it's unknown why it didn't work for you. "vulnerability alert regarding loadsh." - what alert? A common mistake is to try to solve vulnerability problem that doesn't exist in the first place because there's no attack vector.

It's for sure used by some dependency, you can search globally in your project and then you will be able to trace which package installed lodash, by looking at package-lock file or in node_modules structure.

lodash is being installed as axios pre-required packages so it will be not complicitly mentioned in packages.json, I suggest to upgrade to vue3 then the related packages will be upgraded too.
The lodash issue will not be solved until upgrading the vite | webpack and vue.
